Set p4 to use softlink to client as actual client
In a CentOS system, I have a client created at a disk /project/user/my_client
However I work need to have it instead in my home, thats why I have a symlink in for the whole client in my home /home/username/Perforce/mY_client -> /project/user/my_client.
However when I do for example "p4 sync /home/username/Perforce/my_client/..." I get an error that the file is not in clients root.
Looking through some stuff on the internet I tried setting P4CLIENTPATH to /home/username/Perforce/my_client however now I am getting error that the file is not inside permitted filesystem path /project/user/my_client/
How can I get perforce to treat the symlink at my home like its the actual client.
Note that I MUST have the client on that disk and MUST have the symlink in my home, no other way to do it.

Most of the configuration for your client is in the client spec stored on the server.  Run p4 client to edit your client spec.  You can define multiple client roots for a client spec by adding an AltRoots field, e.g.:
Root: /home/username/Perforce/my_client
AltRoots:
    /project/user/my_client

When the server needs to translate a client path to a depot path (like when you run a command with a client path as the argument), it will look at all the possible client roots to see which (if any) it matches, and then use that to map the client path through the client view.
When it needs to translate a depot path to a client path (like when a depot file is being synced to your workspace), it will first look at your CWD to see which root you might be in, and use that root for the translation (defaulting to the Root if you're not in any of them).
